# Trying to vertically 3 align fractions - one has a hidden rule

Tags: alignment, fractions, vertical, baseline

Im attempting to align the X12 over X12 with the fractions. It looks OK until I make the text LARGE then the vertical alignment is off - I think I need to change the baseline for the X12 over X12 but i cant work out how to do it - I've tried various methods frac, genfrac, over, atop but nothing seems to work.
Its simple maths for highschoolers on a website - we use LATEX to display equations

This is what im attempting

```
\LARGE \color{DarkGreen} \frac {1}{2}  \color{RED} {\times 12 \atop  \times 12} = \color{DarkGreen} \frac{12}{24}
```

or

```
\LARGE \genfrac{}{}{}{}{1}{2} \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{\times 12}{\times 12} =  \genfrac{}{}{}{}{12}{24}
```

It results in this[image]

And i need this
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Using any negative value for the line width seems to make a good output: `\mathcolor{green}{\frac{1}{2}} \mathcolor{red}{\genfrac{}{}{-0.0001pt}{}{\times 12}{\times 12} = } \mathcolor{green}{\frac{12}{24}}`.

Comment: That worked!!
\LARGE\color{green}{\frac{1}{2}} \LARGE\color{red}{\genfrac{}{}{-0.0001pt}{}{\times 12}{\times 12} = } \LARGE\color{green}{\frac{12}{24}} 

\mathcolor dosnt work - it crashes my page but color is fine.
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the solution - not that it's necessary but do you know why a negative value for the rule makes it work but a 0 value doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

First off, you cannot use `\LARGE` in math mode. You get *something* like applying `\LARGE`, but not everything.

If you properly use `\LARGE` *outside* the formula, you obtain the expected result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\LARGE $\displaystyle
  \color{DarkGreen} \frac {1}{2}
  \color{red} \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{\times 12}{\times 12} =
  \color{DarkGreen} \frac{12}{24}
$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I loaded `xcolor` with the `svgnames` in order to get the colors, your setup probably calls it in some way and maybe also defines `RED`.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works by using three fraction terms and hiding the fraction line of the second of the three terms.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand\myfrac[3][Red]{%
  \begingroup
  \color{white} % hide the fraction line
  \frac{\mathcolor{#1}{#2}}{\mathcolor{#1}{#3}}
  \endgroup}

\begin{document}

\normalsize
\[
\color{DarkGreen}
\frac{1}{2}
\,\,  
\color{Red}
\myfrac{\times 12}{\times 12}
= 
\color{DarkGreen}
\frac{12}{24}
\]

\huge
\[
\color{DarkGreen}
\frac{1}{2}
\,\,
\color{Red}
\myfrac[blue]{\times 12}{\times 12}
=
\color{DarkGreen}
\frac{12}{24}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that - I can't 'call' packages - I have no control of the environment and I don't know what packages are installed - I know \raisebox doesn't work and i can't get that solution to work in its current form. I think it needs to be inline - the implementation of Latex or Tex is only for web display purposes so it is limited in what can be called.

Comment: @Durutti - It would have been really helpful if you had mentioned in your query that you cannot load LaTeX packages. (Aside: If you're not allowed to load LaTeX packages, how come that you can use `\genfrac`, a macro that's provided by the `amsmath` package?) Please also note that I've edited my answer in the meantime; it no longer employs `\raisebox` instructions.

Comment: I dont know - i dont know whats installed and some things work and some things dont!

Comment: Why the downvote, a month *after* the answer got posted?

Comment: don't know - it wasn't me!